# What does 'lends to' mean in “Social media as a networked economy lends to social activism and online communities.”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am writing a paper for college and one of the questions is this:

> Social media as a networked economy **lends to** social activism and online communities. Assess this assertion critically with a case study.

I tried searching on the internet as to what 'lends to' means and it says I give something to someone or something. But how does this definition make sense in the question above? Can someone explain to me what 'lends to' means in the sentence above?

Comment: It seems like an ill-chosen word to me. The entire sentence doesn't make much sense. Are they saying that social media is/are a networked economy? "Lends to?" "Tends to?"

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lend+to

Answer (score 1):

The correct idiom is **lends *itself* to something.**

It is similar to **facilitates** or **makes possible** or **helps create.** So a rough paraphrase of your sentence is this:

> Social media as a networked economy helps social activism and online communities to exist.

Without **itself**, the idiom is broken. I'm sure the author knew what they meant, but they simply wrote a poor sentence.

I have been a university-level instructor since 1986. Do *not* assume that your instructors are excellent writers. I revise my colleagues' work all the time.

EDIT: I don't mean they all write poorly. I learned a lot about writing from a geology professor. I just mean that a graduate degree does not *guarantee* writing expertise.

Comment: Thanks. That makes much more sense. I definitely agree the instructor has written this sentence poorly. Through my experience, I have come across many instructors who write questions in a way that can cause massive confusion. I appreciate your input. Good day!